# How to keep my score counter on screen?

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there any way to keep my current score counter on screen? or do i need to create another method? My code is as follows (not the final script of course, i just want to get a prototype working before I polish it (:  )

```
var score:Number = 0;
var myScoreBox:TextField = new TextField(); 
var myScore:String = ("Score:"+ score); 
myScoreBox.text = myScore;
addChild(myScoreBox);
myScoreBox.x = player.x;
myScoreBox.y = player.y - 200;
```

I've also created a different method (seen below) but that one doesn't display the value of the "score" number when it's set to zero and does not update whenever points are added to the variable.

```
var score:Number = 0;
trace("The score is", score);
var str:String = ("Score:");
txt.text = str +(score); // now "score 1"
```

So basically, the code on top displays what i want it to but doesnt follow the character and the bottom does the inverse of that! Any help is greatly appreciated!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the `txt.text` with new score whenever your score variable is updated. The best approach is to write a setter function:

```
private var _score:Number=0;
public function set score(value:Number):void {
    _score=value;
    txt.text="Score: "+_score.toString(); // provide correct name for text field!
}
```

A getter function might be necessary in some cases too, because of the variable's visibility modifier:

```
public function get score():Number { return _score; }
```

Comment: Apparently, he knows how to set, his question is: "How to make the textfield 'follow' the player".

Comment: @Zhafur This is to be added to the second solution of his.

Comment: Thanks! I can't seem to get the darn thing working but I now  understand the logistics of what i need to do! Hopefully I can finish it sometime today or tomorrow and then update with what I did.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using some kind of Camera class what you have downloaded or just simply moving the stage. The best practice however, would be to seperate UI and the Game itself. You should create a hierarchy like this:

```
MAIN_CONTAINER
->UI_CONTAINER
-->SCORE TEXT FIELD, HUD...
->GAME_CONTAINER //MOVE THIS CONTAINER [1]
-->PLAYER, ENEMIES, OBJECTS...
[1] GAME_CONTAINER.x = -player.x+[your stage's width]; GAME_CONTAINER.y = -player.y+[your stage's height];
```